# I can not set default value in select option(Angular)

Tags: angular, select

I have crud application. When I write edit, i need set default input and set deault select option. For input all is good. For select  is not set default value.I know about property selected, but it is not work.
**edit-component:**

```
     export class EditStudComponent implements OnInit {

     stud: Stud=new Stud();
     grs: Array<Gr>;
     sub: Subscription;
     selected: Gr;



    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
    studService: StudService, private grService: GrService ) {


    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      if (id) {
        this.studService.getStud(id).subscribe((stud: any) => {
          if (stud) {
            this.stud = stud;

            this.selected=this.stud.gr;
             console.log(this.stud);

            console.log(this.selected);

          } else {
            console.log(`Car with id '${id}' not found, returning to list`);
            this.gotoList();
          }
        });
      }
     });

     this.grService.getGrs()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.grs = data;
      });

    }

    editStud(): void {
      this.studService.updateStud(this.stud)
        .subscribe( data => {
          alert("Edit successfully.");
        });

    };

    }
```

**edit.html**

```
 <select  class="form-control"    id="group" name="gr" size="1" 
[(ngModel)]="stud.gr" >

 <option  *ngFor="let gr of grs"    name="groups" 

[ngValue]="gr"  [selected]="gr==selected">

{{gr.name}}</option>
```

**and screen:[edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls5YR.png)**

Comment: Can you produce your error on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wexfzo?

Answer (score 1):

You should compare `selected.name == gr.name`, instead of comparing two objects.

```
<select  class="form-control" id="group" name="gr" size="1" [(ngModel)]="stud.gr">
 <option  *ngFor="let gr of grs" name="groups" [ngValue]="gr" 
[selected]="gr.name==selected.name">
{{gr.name}}</option>
```

Comment: This is not work. what should return property selected?

Comment: in console i get this error EditStudComponent.html:33 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you checked the demo link?

Comment: That is probably because of asynchronous process. Use safe navigation operator `?.` Try `selected?.name == gr?.name`

Comment: i try this. the error disappeared, but default value null

Comment: What do you mean by default value? You want to set '--Select--' as a default value if nothing matches?

Comment: You can do this for default '--Select--', if no value matches. `<option [selected]="selected?.name==null" value="">-- Select --</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I spread my solution:

```
if (stud) {
            this.stud.patronymic = stud.patronymic;        
            this.stud.course=stud.course;
            this.stud.firstName=stud.surName;
            this.stud.idStud=stud.idStud;
            this.stud.surName=stud.surName;

            this.selected=stud.gr;
             console.log(this.stud);

            console.log(this.selected);
```

edit.html

```
 <option  *ngFor="let gr of grs"    name="grs" 

   [ngValue]="gr"  [selected]="gr?.name==selected?.name">

  {{gr.name}}</option>
```

But the solution is not trivial. Can anyone suggest anything else?